# Unable to connect to Heroku Redis from Node Server

Tags: heroku, redis, ioredis, heroku-redis

Works well on connecting to Redis locally and through Official Redis Docker image. But, when I switch to Heroku Redis values for ENV variables. It is unable to connect.

I have tried full url option as well, but that doesn't seem to work for any Redis connections when I need to add options object as 2nd parameter to `new Redis()`, Url option works if I don't pass any options for only locally and Official Redis Docker image.

Adding only heroku redis URI with no options to new Redis(), looks like it works, but then I get `Redis Connection Failure` after 10 seconds.

Does Heroku-Redis need some sort of extra preparation step?

```js
import Redis, { RedisOptions } from 'ioredis';
import logger from '../logger';

const REDIS_HOST = process.env.REDIS_HOST || '127.0.0.1';
const REDIS_PORT = Number(process.env.REDIS_PORT) || 6379;
const REDIS_PASSWORD = process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD;
const REDIS_DB = Number(process.env.REDIS_DB) || 0;

const redisConfig: RedisOptions = {
  host: REDIS_HOST,
  port: Number(REDIS_PORT),
  password: REDIS_PASSWORD,
  db: Number(REDIS_DB),
  retryStrategy: function (times) {
    if (times % 4 == 0) {
      logger.error('Redis reconnect exhausted after 4 retries');
      return null;
    }
    return 200;
  },
};

const redis = new Redis(redisConfig);
redis.on('error', function () {
  logger.error('Redis Connection Failure');
});

export default redis;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got the idea to use environment variables called `REDIS_HOST`, `REDIS_PORT`, `REDIS_PASSWORD`, and `REDIS_DB`. Heroku Data for Redis [provides a single environment variable that captures all of this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#create-an-instance):

> After Heroku Data for Redis has been created, the new release is created and the application restarts. A `REDIS_URL` config var is available in the app configuration. It contains the URL you can use to access the newly provisioned Heroku Data for Redis instance.

Here is [their example of how to connect from Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-redis#connecting-in-node-js):

> ```js
> const redis = require("redis");
>
> const client = redis.createClient({
>   url: process.env.REDIS_URL,  
>   socket: {
>     tls: true,
>     rejectUnauthorized: false
>   }
> });
> ```

So, change your configuration object accordingly:

```js
const REDIS_URL = process.env.REDIS_URL;

const redisConfig: RedisOptions = {
  url: REDIS_URL,              // <--
  socket: {                    // <--
    tls: true,                 // <--
    rejectUnauthorized: false  // <--
  },                           // <--
  retryStrategy: function (times) {
    if (times % 4 == 0) {
      logger.error('Redis reconnect exhausted after 4 retries');
      return null;
    }
    return 200;
  },
};
```

You are already using an environment variable locally to set your Redis password locally. Replace that with an appropriate `REDIS_URL` that contains all of your defaults, e.g. something like this:

```bash
REDIS_URL=redis://user:password@host:port/database
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris, although I am using `ioredis` package which they do have an example of below the `redis` package. The reason I separated it out is because that is how I got it work through `docker-compose`. Thought I could just destructure the url to appropriate parts and it would still work. Heroku Redis now works, although my local dev now breaks with `REDIS_URL`.  Container name is `redis` and this what I have locally, `redis://redis:6379`, have tried `redis://:password@redis:6379` and this `redis://:@redis:6379`, but nothing.

Comment: Are you using [the official `redis` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis)? By default it runs with protected mode disabled. Have you changed this via your own config file?

Comment: The issue ended up being the `tls` block. when using docker compose, omit the `tls` block. when heroku, keep it like you have it `rejectUnauthorized: false`.